# How to add data to firebase using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an admin panel where the user enters car details and it maps to my firebase real-time database.When the user hits save , the input fields has should be mapped to the database. I have tried everything out there but it simply wont work.

When I hit on save , i get the following error:

```
validation.ts:145 Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'cars.New car.newCar.transmission'
at rc (validation.ts:145)
at validation.ts:204
at Cu (util.ts:417)
at rc (validation.ts:185)
at validation.ts:204
at Cu (util.ts:417)
at rc (validation.ts:185)
at Hu (validation.ts:122)
at Df.set (Reference.ts:137)
at addData (addcar.html:96)
```

The following is my html and javascript code.

```js
//config is add here
  // initialize firebase  
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  //this.database = firebase.database();
  
  function addData()
  {
    var databaseRef= firebase.database().ref();
    var storesRef =databaseRef.child('Cars/new car');
    var addCar = storesRef.push();
    
    addCar.set({
        name:$("#car-name").val(),
        transmission:$("#car_transmission").val()
    });

  }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/public/admin.html">
            Rentacabs Admin
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown navbar-right">
            <button 
            id="user-email"
            class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
            >
                incubsolutions@gmail.com
            </button>

            <div 
                class="dropdown-menu"
                aria-labeledby="user-email"
            >
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="btn-logout" href="#">
                    Logout
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<h2>Cars</h2>

<hr />

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <h4>Add new</h4>
        <form id="category-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="car-name">Enter car name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="car-name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fuel_type">Fuel Type</label>
                <select name="" class="form-control" id="fuel_type">
                    <option value="petrol">Petrol</option>
                    <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="car_milege">Milege</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="car_milege" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="car_transmission">Transmission</label>
                <select name="" class="form-control" id="fuel_type">
                    <option value="automatic">Automatic</option>
                    <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="car_rate">rate per km</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="car_rate" />
            </div>
            <div class="from-group">
                <button id="save-car" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addData()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

any help is appreciated, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you reuse the `fuel_type` id for your `transmission` field:

```
 <label for="car_transmission">Transmission</label>
 <select name="" class="form-control" id="fuel_type">
 //....
```

---

And then you have another problem: your button is of type               `type="submit"`. Your form is submitted **before** the Firebase method is triggered. You should change the button type to `button`. See the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for more detail on button types.

Comment: but still nothing is added to my database

Comment: See the update I've just done, about the button type.

Comment: Note there was a typo in my last update! :-) You should read: "You should change the button type to `button`".